# To establish a server in Ubuntu which version should I install Desktop version or the server edition?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, software-installation, webserver

I know Ubuntu has a distribution which is for server purposes (Ubuntu Server Edition). But:

- Is it necessary to use Ubuntu Server Edition?
- Will working on Ubuntu only works?

   Please shade some lights about **Prerequisites About Ubuntu Server Installation**

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just using ubuntu for a server then it would be wise to use ubuntu server edition. If you are looking to do other stuff including using a server, you can install ubuntu desktop. It is not necessary to use ubuntu server for a server.

If you going to use ubuntu desktop, then using [this tutorial](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu), you can get a server up and running.

Comment: Cruz Your link says Ubuntu LAMP Server successfully installed. Is UBUNTU SERVER EDITION and UBUNTU LAMP SERVER same?

Comment: LAMP includes MySQL, PHP, and Apache2. Ubuntu Server Edition uses the same things, but ubuntu server doesn't come with a gui, and you'd get a few more features. But if you go with the LAMP way, you could add more features if needed.

Comment: If you install Desktop and afterwards the server applications (Apache, php, MySQL, whatever you like..), you might have a bit more work to get the server apps configured nicely (or not, it depends). On the other hand, if you install Server first, you'll need to do some job installing X and the rest of the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Server will not ask you if you want autologin, will not allow easy connection to WiFi via Unity and Network Manager. You will be working in linux virtual terminal, installing Xorg, setting things up yourself. I recently installed Server and noted those things. It was like if I had to restore Xorg myself, and configure Network Manager via command line. That's fine thing to do, I had Server before and it was fine, but now I placed the netbook in such a place that it's hard to sit in front of it :) And without instant WiFi connection SSH wasn't an option. So I just didn't want to play into DIY game and reinstalled with Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Nice, It made you  know some new commands though, :)